# How to find pythagorean triples underneath a user entered number in c

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program in c where the user enters a positive integer and the program calculates all of the triples underneath that number, list them all, and then states the triple with the largest c value (using for,if, and else). This the code I have now, it will take the number I enter and use it as the triple (ie: I enter 15, it prints that there is one triple (15,15,15) etc) just wondering how I could fix this if you know? thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, max, counter;
    int N;
    int maxA=1, maxB=1, maxC=1;
    {
        printf("Enter a positive integer:");
        scanf("%d", &N);
        {
            for (c=1; c<N; c++);
            {
                for (b=1; b<c; b++);
                {
                    for (a=1; a<N; a++);
                    {
                        if (a*a+b*b==c*c)
                            counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    {
        printf("There are %d pythagorean triples in this range\n", max);
        {
            for (c=1; c<N; c++);
            {
                for (b=1; b<c; b++);
                {
                    for (a=1; a<N; a++);
                    {
                        if (a*a + b*b== c*c)
                            printf("(%d1, %d2, %d3) pythagorean triples\n", a,b,c);
                        if (c>max);
                        {
                            max = maxC;
                            max = maxB;
                            max = maxA;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The pythagorean triple with the largest c value is (%d,%d, %d)\n", a,b,c);
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no code-review site.

Comment: How does the code you have now work? Does it build? Does it run? Does it give any kind of result? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected your code:

Your `for` loops had a terminating `;` at the end.

`counter` was used uninitialized.

`"%d1"` in the `printf` prints the number and a `1` after it, which leads to wrong numbers.

You have overwritten your `max` variable 3 times instead of using `maxA`, `maxB` and  `maxC` after finding a new highest triple. You also forgot to add braces there, it should only do this with triples and not every time.

I also removed the unnecessary braces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, counter = 0;
    int N;
    int maxA=1, maxB=1, maxC=1;
    printf("Enter a positive integer:");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for (c=1; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (b=1; b<c; b++)
        {
            for (a=1; a<N; a++)
            {
                if (a*a+b*b==c*c)
                    counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("There are %d pythagorean triples in this range\n", counter);

    for (c=1; c<N; c++)
    {
        for (b=1; b<c; b++)
        {
            for (a=1; a<N; a++)
            {
                if (a*a + b*b== c*c)
                {
                    printf("(%d, %d, %d) pythagorean triples\n", a,b,c);
                    if (c>maxC);
                    {
                        maxC = c;
                        maxB = b;
                        maxA = a;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("The pythagorean triple with the largest c value is (%d,%d, %d)\n", maxA,maxB,maxC);
    return 0;
}
```